# Kinetic.Global.extend() is not a function

Tags: kineticjs

I have some old code that I'm updating to the latest version (4.5.4) and it is giving me the error that Kinetic.Global.extend() is not a function.

I checked and extend() isn't listed in the docs, but is mentioned in the forums. Has it been recently removed? How do I replicate this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
Kinetic.Util.extend
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there somewhere these changes are documented? The change log doesn't list this kind of detail... ?